# Two position switch custom control in wpf/c#

Tags: wpf, controls

I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to implement a two position switch in WPF.
Here is how should it look like:

[two position switch http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/1439/wl3b.png](http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/1439/wl3b.png)

Maybe such control does exist already?

Requirements:

- it should be possible to set images (or a content) in place of labels (O/I)
- labels are transformed depending on the switch position
- switch overlaps the border if it's in upper position

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a `ToggleButton` to me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you look for something like [ToggleSwitch](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233583/WPFSpark-2-of-n-ToggleSwitch)